# Node js Application cannot call method of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I use the Crawler Ninja plugin, found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler-ninja in combination with plugin expired domains. 
https://github.com/christophebe/expired-domains.ninja

However on my first "try" it returned me some vague errors.
The first was a typo I believe and I changed it

```
console.log(ed.expireds.keys())
```

to

```
console.log(end.expireds.keys())
```

ERROR WAS :

```
console.log(ed.expireds.keys())
                ^
ReferenceError: ed is not defined
```

NOW I FACE A NEW ERROR :

```
[root@vps-121706-2576 node_modules]# node ttt.js
Use log in : /root/plg/node_modules/logs/crawler.log
Well done Sir !, done in : 170389

/root/plg/node_modules/ttt.js:22
    console.log(end.expireds.keys())
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'keys' of undefined
```

QUESTION :

Don't understand the error and how to fix it.
Should one need more info or details, just comment.

CODE PLUGIN :

```
var crawler     = require("crawler-ninja");
var ep          = require("crawler-ninja-expired");

crawl();

function crawl(){
var c = new crawler.Crawler({
    externalDomains : true,
    images : false,
    scripts : false,
    links : false, //link tags used for css, canonical, ...
    followRedirect : true
});

var expired = new ep.Plugin(c);

c.on("end", function() {

    var end = new Date();
    console.log("Well done Sir !, done in : " + (end - start));
    // the attributes expireds is a map with a key that match to the expired domains
    console.log(end.expireds.keys())



});

var start = new Date();
c.queue({url : "http://www.erijane.nl/"});
}
```

Comment: Why -1 ? I tried to structure the question and code properly. At least when you -1 explain why..

Answer (score 1):

`end` is a `Date` object, that does not have a `expireds` property.

Perhaps you just need the `expired` object that was defined like:

```
var expired = new ep.Plugin(c);
```

or maybe you need the `ep` object instead of `ed` or `end`.

<sup>*Truth be told, I don't know the library, just making guesses.*</sup>

Comment: Maybe I did not correct my first error properly and ed was good after all. But then im stucked with error : ReferenceError: ed is not defined

Comment: Always nice when they give you an wrong example to start from, many thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look again. Also thanks for taking the time and effort to read and answer.

Answer (score 0):

as [crawler-ninja-expired](https://github.com/christophebe/expired-domains.ninja) README said: it's ** work in progress **..

also, i've read the source code, there is no such thing like `expired()` or `expired = {}`

so basically there is nothing you can do :(